# "You are not authorized to perform this action" Error with Channel Favorites

Tags: system

I've got a site I made for one of my hobbies and to play around with new EE tricks (and just so I can have a site that is mine to do with as I please!). Note, there are still some links and features (search) that don't do anything, one step at a time.

However recently the Channel Favorites "like" function stopped working. I get the generic "You are not authorized to perform this action" message from the EE system. I have looked at my Blacklist, nothing there. I tried it logged in as guest, a member, and super admin...nothing. I even turned off the security feature that prevents duplicate data.

It works on my local and development versions just fine. If I export my production database to development it still works. You can see the development and production versions here:

http://dev.rcdevotee.com

http://www.rcdevotee.com

I've checked system file/folder permissions, CP paths, and everything else I can think of. What else am I missing?

Code is here (same code on dev and www, but only works on dev):

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="models" dynamic="yes" track_views="one" require_entry="yes" disable="pagination|member_data" cache="no" refresh="1440"}
....

<div class="like block">
{exp:channel_ratings:likes entry_id="{entry_id}"}
{if rating:not_voted}
{exp:channel_ratings:new_like entry_id="{entry_id}" allow_guests="yes"}
<div class="like_btn"><a class="btn" href="{rating:like_url}">I like this</a></div>
{/exp:channel_ratings:new_like}
{/if}
{if rating:voted}
<div class="like_btn">You liked this</div>
{/if}
<ul class="">
<li class="fa fa-trophy total_likes">{rating:liked} likes</li>
<li class="icomoon-eye">{view_count_one} views</li>
</ul>
{/exp:channel_ratings:likes}
</div><!-- .likeblock -->
...
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: We will probably need to see your template code to be of any help.

Comment: added the EE template code

Comment: I had an issue similar on my local environment in the past and I think I fixed it by uninstalling the module and reinstalling it. Are you able to try that? If it is a live site with lots of data might not be the best first step as you will lose all of the data.